# Creating a helper class in Android for storing variables

Tags: android-activity, android

I'm making a music app, which has a lot of variables flying around as songs are chosen, based on artists & albums and all sorts of things.

I'm trying to make my app a bit easier to use by sending all of those variables out to a new class, which I consider as kind of like a 'helper cell' in excel.. It stores a bunch of data so I don't have to keep passing and receiving extras.

The idea is this:

The user chooses a song, and the artist/album/song information is passed out to the helper class.

Next, a music service starts, taking the chosen songs path from the helper class, and playing it.

At the same time, an activity starts, displaying the chosen artist/album/song, again, from the helper class. Next/previous buttons are included here, and once clicked, the helper class' current song is changed, and the music service is instructed to receive the variables from the helper class again.

What type of class would this be? What would it extent, how can I instantiate it, and how can I send and receive variables to/from that class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an Application instance to hold application-level variables.

1. Extend `android.app.application`
2. Define your application in the AndroidManifest.xml

   ```
   <application android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher" android:label="@string/app_name" android:name=".MainApplication">
   ```
3. To get your application instance in your activities, call `getApplication()`

For example, in your onCreate() method of your activity, you would use this code, assuming you named your application class "MainApplication":

```
Application application = ((MainApplication)getApplication());
Album album = application.getAlbum();
Song song = application.getSong();
...
```

Comment: Thanks IncrediApp. Could you provde an example of getApplication, or show me how it's used? Can do I have to call whenever I want to retrieve a variable from the application?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what the exact implementation you are trying to do, you could also use SharedPreferences to store these variables and change them as needed it when a new song is selected, etc. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref